# Python, how can I print the current datetime on the same line as a text message?

Tags: python, python-2.4

First experiences with Python here, I want to be able to print out some text with the current time/date as the first item on the line.

This is what I've been able to cook up so far, but it appears I'm syntactically incorrect, can someone please correct me?

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import datetime

remote_host = "127.0.0.1"

now = datetime.datetime.now()

for remote_port in [9002,8080]:
        now_text = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(60)
        try:
                sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
        except Exception,e:
                print "%d %d closed " % now_text remote_port
        else:
                print  "%d %d open" % now_text remote_port
        sock.close()
```

Kind regards

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.4.3 -  print  "%d %d open" % (now_text, remote_port)
TypeError: int argument required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
print "%d %d closed" % (now_text, remote_port)
```

For future reference, here's one way to do that in Python 3:

```
print("{0} {1} closed".format(now_text, remote_port))
```

The [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method was introduced in Python 2.6.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however it should be `%s %d` and not two d's. thanks :)

Comment: The nice thing about `.format()` is you don't have to worry about types like that.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible errors (the second one definite):

1. `Exception,e` needs to be replaced by `Exception as e` (depending on the Python version).
2. The % operator requires a tuple argument: `"%d %d closed" % (a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print "%s %d closed " % (now_text,remote_port)
2011-03-15 14:46 9002 closed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take:

```
#the code below will print the date and time on separate lines.

from datetime import datetime
now =datetime.now()

print('%s/%s/%s' %(now.month,now.day,now.year))
print('%s:%s:%s' %(now.hour,now.minute,now.second))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this does not answer the question. Plus, this post is 6+ years old with accepted answer.